# ion-router toast on route

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, stenciljs, capacitor

I'm using stencil basic app integrated with redux and all together with capacitor. I would like to present a toast when an error occurred. My `app-root.tsx` looks like this:

```
    @State() error: any;

    componentWillLoad() {
        this.store.setStore(configureStore({}));

        this.store.mapStateToProps(this, (state: RootState) => {
            const { error, isStatusBarLight } = state.app;
            return { error, isStatusBarLight };
        });
    }

    @Watch('isStatusBarLight')
    onIsStatusBarLightChange() {
        return this.setStatusBarStyle();
    }

    async setStatusBarStyle() {
        try {
            await StatusBar.setStyle({
                style: this.isStatusBarLight ? StatusBarStyle.Dark : StatusBarStyle.Light,
            });
        } catch (err) {
            this.error = err.toString();
        }
    }

    @Watch('error')
    onErrorChange(err: string) {
        if (err) {
            this.toast.message = err;
            this.toast.duration = 2000;
            return this.toast.present();
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ion-app>
                <ion-router useHash={false}>
                    <ion-route url='/' component='app-home' />
                    <ion-route url='/settings' component='app-settings' />
                </ion-router>
                <ion-nav />
                <ion-toast message='' duration={2000} ref={elm => this.toast = elm}></ion-toast>
            </ion-app>
        );
    }
```

It works smoothly when in `app-root` view. But when `isStatusBarLight` is changed in `app-settings`, this `app-root` component receives the event via `mapStateToProps` but does not show the toast. Also I receive a console log:

> The "ionToastWillPresent" event was emitted, but the dispatcher node
>   is not longer connected to the dom.

I've also tried to add and remove toast in render function, depending whether if there is an error or not, but this leads to an error if the toast is removed before it is auto hidden (i.e. because a state change). Then it stops showing toasts in child views. Also I'm not sure if this is an optimal way:

```
render() {
    return (
        <ion-app>
            <ion-router useHash={false}>
                <ion-route url='/' component='app-home' />
                <ion-route url='/settings' component='app-settings' />
            </ion-router>
            <ion-nav />
            {this.error ? <ion-toast message={this.error} duration={2000} ref={elm => elm.present()}></ion-toast> : null}
        </ion-app>
    );
}
```

I'm not looking for a workaround, I'm looking a way to present modals and toasts in the whole app, having a unified way to present this kind of messages to user via app state. Please, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I've resolved by creating a new toast each time:

```
@Element() me: HTMLElement;

@Watch('error')
onErrorChange(err: string) {
    if (err) {
        const toast: HTMLIonToastElement = document.createElement('ion-toast');
        toast.message = err;
        toast.duration = 2000;
        toast.onDidDismiss().then(() => toast.remove());
        this.me.appendChild(toast);

        return toast.present();
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}

render() {
    return (
        <ion-app>
            <ion-router useHash={false}>
                <ion-route url='/' component='app-home' />
                <ion-route url='/settings' component='app-settings' />
            </ion-router>
            <ion-nav />
        </ion-app>
    );
}
```